# find strings common in at least two data sets

Tags: r, set, intersection

I have 4 data sets (a,b,c,d) and I want to find strings that are present in at least two of the data sets. My data looks like this:

```
 head(a)
```

> ```
> [1] MLH3      PCSK7     PKMYT1    C14orf132 ANP32A    POLQ     
> 1634 Levels: AARS ABAT ABCA8 ABCC9 ABCE1 ABHD3 ABHD5 ABL1 ABLIM1 ACADVL ACAN ACAT2 ACBD3     ACD ACLY ACOT2 .
> ```

```
head(b)
```

> ```
> [1] ZCCHC10  DYNLL1   ERBB2IP  C17orf75 BUB1B    PLK1    
>  1311 Levels: AASDHPPT ABAT ABCA6 ABCG1 ABI1 ACAA1 ACACB ACO2 ACOX1 ACSL1 ACSL3 ACSL4     ACTR6 ADAMTS1 ADCYAP1R1 ... ZRANB2
> ```

```
head(c)
```

> ```
> [1] UBE2Q1    PCSK9     ZDHHC11   GMDS      PPP2R3B   C20orf117
> 1247 Levels: ABCC2 ABCC5 ABCF1 ABCG1 ABHD14B ABHD5 ABL1 ABLIM2 ABTB2 ACAD8 ACD ACO1 ACOT9 ACSL3 ACSS2 ACTA2 ... ZYG11B
> ```

```
head(d)
```

> ```
> [1] UBE2Q1    PCSK9     ZDHHC11   GMDS      PPP2R3B   C20orf117
> 1247 Levels: ABCC2 ABCC5 ABCF1 ABCG1 ABHD14B ABHD5 ABL1 ABLIM2 ABTB2 ACAD8 ACD ACO1 ACOT9 ACSL3 ACSS2 ACTA2 ... ZYG11B
> ```

I am thinking of using the `intersect()` function in R

Comment: It's odd that this question is tagged with both `r` and `python`.  Do you intend that your solution will include code in both Python and R?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a list of the unique elements in each of your four vectors and just return the duplicated elements, which are the elements appearing in two or more of the vectors:

```
all.vals <- c(unique(a), unique(b), unique(cc), unique(d))
unique(all.vals[duplicated(all.vals)])
# [1] "UBE2Q1"    "PCSK9"     "ZDHHC11"   "GMDS"      "PPP2R3B"   "C20orf117"
```

Note that I renamed your third vector to be `cc` so you didn't overwrite the built-in function `c`:

```
a <- c("MLH3", "PCSK7", "PKMYT1", "C14orf132", "ANP32A", "POLQ")
b <- c("ZCCHC10", "DYNLL1", "ERBB2IP", "C17orf75", "BUB1B", "PLK1")
cc <- c("UBE2Q1", "PCSK9", "ZDHHC11", "GMDS", "PPP2R3B", "C20orf117")
d <- c("UBE2Q1", "PCSK9", "ZDHHC11", "GMDS", "PPP2R3B", "C20orf117")
```

Comment: would this give the strings that are found in at least two?

Comment: Yes, this is strings found in two or more.